# Context load fail during deploying application in jboss EAP 6 from weblogic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jboss6.x

I am facing below issue while deploying application in Jboss. This is deploying fine in weblogic.

Can anyone please help on this.I verified the JNDI is working fine but not sure why this issue is coming.

> ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 114) Context initialization failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userService' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-services.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'userDao' while setting bean property 'usersDao';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property
>   'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of the
>   FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type
>   name: com.app.test.service.DashboardService